# Chainlink External adapter job can't get data in solidity contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I have created a chainlink node and bridge for an external adapter which fetches data from openweathermap api. the job works fine and I am getting result. but somehow I couldn't get that value inside the smart contract. can anyone help me. I have attached the screenshots of my code

This oracle runs on Kovan network. Here is my sample Job Spec:

```
{
  "initiators": [
    {
      "type": "runlog",
      "params": {
        "address": "ADDRESS_REDACTED"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "openweather"
    },
    {
      "type": "copy"
    },
    {
      "type": "multiply"
    },
    {
      "type": "ethuint256"
    }
  ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fhLy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding ethtx at the end of your job specification https://docs.chain.link/docs/adapters#ethtx Your node address should also contain some eth balance.